# react native push notification sound

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification

I am trying to add sound to my local push notification.
I am using RN 0.45.1 and
react-native-push-notifications 3.0.0

I manage to schedule notification in iOS and Android with default sound.
I did not manage to add custom sound.

I have sounds file of type mp3.
I tried the following:

1. place the file in my project folder:
   '/src/assests/sounds/sound.mps' (a folder inside my project)

and than:

```
import notificationSound from '../src/assests/sounds/sound.mps';

PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
            message: 'Test message',
            date: new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000)),
            repeatType: 'time',
            repeatTime: 60 * 1000,
            sound: notificationSound,
        });
```

2. another attempt was:
   putting the sound file under android folder: ..\android\app\src\main\res\raw\sound.mp3

and the notification was:

```
   PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
            message: 'Test message',
            date: new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000)),
            repeatType: 'time',
            repeatTime: 60 * 1000,
            sound: sound.mp3,
        });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is property for sound

`soundName: 'default',`

Sound to play when the notification is shown.
A value of 'default' plays the default sound.
It can be set to a custom sound such as android.resource://com.xyz/raw/my_sound'. It will look for the 'my_sound' audio file in 'res/raw' directory and play it. default: 'default' (default sound is played)

For Custom sounds

In android, add your custom sound file to [project_root]/android/app/src/main/res/raw

In iOS, add your custom sound file to the project Resources in xCode.

In the location notification json specify the full file name:

soundName: 'my_sound.mp3'

Comment: hi, I read the documentation in the npm. if you look at my second option I tried what the documentation said but with no luck

Comment: I think you are using on `sound` as param but you need to use `soundName`

so

```sound: sound.mp3,``` is not proper 
```soundName : sound.mp3, ``` is proper

Comment: Thank Nisarg,
I missed in your first reply the 'soundName' property...I was focusing on the file location

Comment: Hello I am Using this is module is it working for this property ... If it is working where i was giving this
https://github.com/urbanairship/react-native-module/issues/63

Comment: Do you know how to play sound if in "do not disturb" mode?

Comment: I think it about phone OD setting and I don't know how to do in this in DND mode

Answer (score 0):

Check the  `scheduleNotif(soundName)` function from the following [example](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/b77c465590e4b83d6a6f3880b2aa0a630099d594/example/NotifService.js#L109) from the `react-native-push-notification` docs. The previous example worked for me on my Android device. Just add the name of the sound file without writing its format "success", not "success.mp3" .. The sound file should be located under the `raw` folder `[project_root]/android/app/src/main/res/raw`

My modified method for my app needs:

```
var lastId = 0;
function scheduleNotif(soundName, date, title, message) {
  lastId++;
  PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    date: new Date(date),
    title: title,
    message: message,
    color: 'blue', 
    invokeApp: false, 

    when: null,
    usesChronometer: false, 
    timeoutAfter: null, 

    
    category: '', // (optional) default: empty string

    id: lastId, 
    userInfo: { sceen: 'home' }, 
    playSound: !!soundName,                        //<-----
    soundName: soundName ? soundName : 'default',  //<-----
    number: 10,
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

please use this payload, before that, need to create a channel. It works for both app is killed state and closed state.

{
"notification":{
"title": "test notification",
"body": "test notification",
"android_channel_id": "channelID"
},
"data":{
"property1":"value1",
"property2":42
}
}