# Use downloaded sounds for push notifications (react-native)

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm wondering if it is possible to download sound files on the fly that can then be used as sounds for Push notifications (on Android and iOS).

The reason for that is that my App should support different Push sounds that should be fetched from the server instead of having them bundled into the App (which would require that the users always update to the latest version).

My idea was to use `react-native-fs` or `react-native-fetch-blob` to download the sounds to whatever location (question #2) if there is any location that can be used for this purpose at all (question #1).

Do you think/know if this is possible or is this in general a bad idea? If so, are there any alternative approaches?

Answer (score -1):

maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591810/react-native-push-notification-sound) answer can be helpful for you.

Or [this](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) library have a section about "Custom Sounds":

> in android, add your custom sound file to [project_root]/android/app/src/main/res/raw
>
> In iOS, add your custom sound file to the project Resources in xCode.
>
> In the location notification json specify the full file name:

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it does not answer my question because I want to download the sounds instead of bundling them into the app.